# RequireJS: Issue with mutually recursive modules

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, parse-platform

I have a `Workout` object and a `WorkoutSection` object. Both use the other for various attributes. The `Workout` does not use `WorkoutSection` during load, however `WorkoutSection` uses `Workout` during load.

WorkoutSection.js

```
define(['require',
    // post-load
    'models/Workout'
], 
function(require) {
    // must require Workout because of mutual dependency
    var Workout = require('models/Workout');
```

Workout.js

```
define([
    'require','models/WorkoutSection'
], 

    function(require) {
        // must re-require Workout because of mutual dependency
        var WorkoutSection;

        var Workout = Parse.Object.extend("Workout",
        {
            initialize : function() {
                WorkoutSection = require('models/WorkoutSection');
            },
```

The error:

> Uncaught Error: Module name "models/Workout" has not been loaded yet
>   for context: _ http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
>   require.js:2 H require.js:2 k.s.newContext.j.require require.js:2
>   requirejs require.js:2 (anonymous function) WorkoutSection.js:20

I am following the solution described in the link, but am still getting the error =S Any ideas that would fix this?

Here's my main.js:

```
// Filename: main.js

// Require.js allows us to configure shortcut alias
// Their usage will become more apparent futher along in the tutorial.
require.config( {
    paths : {
        jQuery : 'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
        Underscore : 'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
        Backbone : 'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
        Parse : 'libs/parse/parse-min',
        templates : '../templates'
    }
});

require( [
    // Load our app module and pass it to our definition function
    'app',
],
function(App) {
    // The "app" dependency is passed in as "App"
    // Again, the other dependencies passed in are not "AMD" therefore
    // don't pass a parameter to this function
    App.initialize();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your main javascript file that calls `require()`?

Comment: I posted my `main.js` which calls `App` which calls `Router`. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you either:

1. try reworking `WorkoutSection.js` into the `CommonJS` format as documented here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule
2. Completely exclude `models/WorkoutSection` as a dependency of `Workout.js`

Comment: I did a variation of (2) - I only use `WorkoutSection` in a single function of `Workout`, so I put `var WorkoutSection = require('models/WorkoutSection');` at the beginning of that function and voila! Thanks!